# Scraping the web for data with a dynamic URL dependent of if/elseif statements

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

The plan is to have a named range of a list of tickers and exchanges then to open a dynamic URL and scrape the data from Yahoo Finance.  The problem is im scraping data from different exchanges so I need an if,elseif statement to splice the URL differently based on the exchange.

At the end of the if statement and With and End With statement I am getting the error "[Expression.Error] the name 'Source' wasn't recognized....".

I simplified only the relevant code and hard coded the symbol as TGIF and exchange as CN to make it easier to understand.

Been searching on every site but cant find anything on this specific error message.  Tried google and no hits so this specific error doesnt seem like it has been addressed before.

```
Sub OpenWebStockDataTest()
'
' OpenWebStockDataTest Macro
'

'
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim exchange As String

    ticker = "TGIF"
    exchange = "XCNQ"

    If exchange = "XCNQ" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & ".CN" & "/history?p=" & ticker & ".CN""""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

    ElseIf exchange = "XTSX" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & ".V" & "/history?p=" & ticker & ".V""""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

    ElseIf exchange = "XTSE" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & ".TO" & "/history?p=" & ticker & ".TO""""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

    ElseIf exchange = "XNYS" Or exchange = "XNAS" Or exchange = "OTCM" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "/history?p="" & ticker""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Name = "stockData"
End Sub
```

It should open a connection to https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TGIF.CN/history?p=TGIF.CN but instead i get the error message.

Comment: someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Expression.Error` message usually indicates that your `M`/Power Query code contains that an undefined/unassigned expression. (One example might be in the fourth branch of your `IF` statement, where your VBA variable `ticker` is inside the Powery Query code itself. But the error message suggests the expression `Source` is the problem.)

---

My suggestion would be to change your approach. If `ticker` and `exchange` are located within some named ranges in your Excel workbook, then an easier approach might be:

- Pick up the values of `ticker` and `exchange` using Power Query directly (instead of using VBA)
- Have some conditional `IF` statements/logic within your Power Query code (instead of VBA) to figure out what the URL should be.
- Query the URL using Power Query (you're already doing this, so no change here).

In theory, the above approach removes the need for VBA but requires that either:

- `ticker` and `exchange` should be in named ranges if your query table is in the same Excel workbook
- or `ticker` and `exchange` need not be in named ranges as long as your query table is in a different workbook.

---

To give you an example, this is a function that, given the name of a range, will let you get that particular named range's contents from the current workbook using Power Query:

```
GetNamedRangeInCurrentWorkbook = (nameOfRange as text) as text => Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=nameOfRange]}[Content][Column1]{0}
```

And this a function that, if you give it a particular exchange and ticker, will try to give you the URL (provided that the exchange you've provided is present within the `exchangeMap` expression/recordset).

```
GetUrlToQuery = (exchangeToQuery as text, tickerValue as text) as text =>
    let
        exchangeMap = [
            XCNQ = ".CN",
            XTSX = ".V",
            XTSE = ".TO"
            // You can continue this for any others that need doing.
        ],
        mappedValue = Record.Field(exchangeMap, exchangeToQuery),
        concatenatedValue = tickerValue & mappedValue,
        url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & concatenatedValue & "/history?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([p = concatenatedValue])
    in url,
```

Putting them together (and assuming you have `exchange` and `ticker` in named ranges), you can then try something like:

```
let
    GetNamedRangeInCurrentWorkbook = (nameOfRange as text) as text => Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=nameOfRange]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    ticker = GetNamedRangeInCurrentWorkbook("ticker"),
    exchange = GetNamedRangeInCurrentWorkbook("exchange"),
    GetUrlToQuery = (exchangeToQuery as text, tickerValue as text) as text =>
        let
            exchangeMap = [
                XCNQ = ".CN",
                XTSX = ".V",
                XTSE = ".TO"
                // You can continue this for any others that need doing.
            ],
            mappedValue = Record.Field(exchangeMap, exchangeToQuery),
            concatenatedValue = tickerValue & mappedValue,
            url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & concatenatedValue & "/history?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([p = concatenatedValue])
        in url,
    url = GetUrlToQuery(exchange, ticker),
    response = Web.Page(Web.Contents(url)),
    data = response{2}[Data],
    changedTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(data, {{"Date", type date}, {"Open", type number}, {"High", type number}, {"Low", type number}, {"Close*", type number}, {"Adj Close**", type number}, {"Volume", type number}})
in
    changedTypes
```

Then, in theory, if the values of `ticker` and `exchange` change, you can simply refresh the query and you should get new data (provided that the new values of `ticker` and `exchange` are valid and supported by the `GetUrlToQuery` function).

Example image (yellow cells are named ranges, query table is loaded beneath):

[image: Output table]

Comment: Hey chillin!  thanks for your detailed solution!  Just to inquire would the method above significantly speed up my run time?  right now to go through a list of about 150 tickers takes about 12-15 mins.  But does above create a dynamic link with Yahoo finance that will automatically update?

Comment: No, in terms of performance, I really doubt there is much of a difference between your approach and mine. I imagine a lot of time is spent waiting to receive a response (from the server). This is a problem with making requests in this kind of serial/synchronous manner.

Comment: My answer mostly focused on moving/simplifying all the conditional `IF` logic into one place (Power Query) -- as it seems awkward to maintain/refresh recorded `M` code via VBA. But I don't think you will see any major reduction in time unless you parallelise these requests (not possible with Power Query as far as I know; even if it was, the server may throttle requests if too many are received within a short space of time) or implement some sort of custom cache (so you wouldn't need to re-fetch resources that you've requested/cached previously).